# How to apply Foreign Key in table model using Sequelize in NodeJs?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, orm, sequelize.js

I am just learning how to use Sequelize in NodeJs to access MySQL database but I got stuck with the foreign key thing while creating the models. Can anyone suggest how shall I apply as I had tried one but it threw error.

**Models**

**exam_category.js**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../../database');

const ExamCategory = sequelize.define('exam_category', {
    id:{ type: Sequelize.BIGINT, autoIncrement: true, allowNull: false, primaryKey: true }, 
    exam_category_name: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false },
    isActive: { type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN, allowNull: false },
    createdBy: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: true },
    createdAt: { type: Sequelize.DATE, allowNull: false }
}, { timestamps: false });

module.exports = ExamCategory;
```

**exam.js**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = require('../../database');

const Exam = sequelize.define('exam', { 
    id:{ type: Sequelize.BIGINT, autoIncrement: true, allowNull: false, primaryKey: true }, 
    startDate: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false }, 
    endDate: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false },
    startTime: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false }, 
    endTime: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false },
    examDuration: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, allowNull: false },
    examName: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false },
    examKey: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false, unique: true },
    exam_category_id: { type: Sequelize.BIGINT, allowNull: false, references: 'exam_category', referencesKey: 'id' },
    isActive: { type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN, allowNull: false },
    createdBy: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: true },
    createdAt: { type: Sequelize.DATE, allowNull: false }
}, { timestamps: false });

module.exports = Exam;
```

Then in **app.js** I wrote this one:

```
const sequelize = require('./database');
const adminUser = require('./models/users/admin_user');
const examCategory = require('./models/users/exam_category');
const exam = require('./models/users/exam');
examCategory.ExamCategory.hasMany(exam.Exam, {
    foreignKey: 'exam_id',
    sourceKey: 'id'
});
exam.Exam.belongsTo( examCategory.ExamCategory, {
    foreignKey: 'exam_id',
    targetKey: 'id'
});
sequelize.sync();
sequelize.sync({ force: true });
```

And this is my **database.js**

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const examCategory = require('./exam_category');

const db = new Sequelize(
    'otp_node', 'root', 'root',
    {
        dialect: 'mysql',
        host: 'localhost'
    }
);
module.exports = db;
```

**ERROR**

> PS D:\practice\otp\frontend> node .\server.js
> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:968   throw err;   ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module './exam_category' Require stack:
>
> - D:\practice\otp\frontend\backend\database.js
> - D:\practice\otp\frontend\backend\app.js
> - D:\practice\otp\frontend\server.js
>   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965:15)
>   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:841:27)
>   at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19)
>   at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
>   at Object. (D:\practice\otp\frontend\backend\database.js:2:22)
>   at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
>   at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
>   at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
>   at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
>   at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1025:19) {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [
>   'D:\practice\otp\frontend\backend\database.js',
>   'D:\practice\otp\frontend\backend\app.js',
>   'D:\practice\otp\frontend\server.js'   ] } PS D:\practice\otp\frontend>

For reference this is my [Github Repo](https://github.com/barefacedbear/node-practice) of the code.
Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Show an error you got

Comment: @Anatoly updated the question with the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this to add foreign Key in your table

`app.js`

```
const sequelize = require('./database');
const adminUser = require('./models/users/admin_user');
const ExamCategory = require('./models/users/exam_category');
const Exam = require('./models/users/exam');
ExamCategory.hasMany(exam, {
    foreignKey: 'exam_id',
    sourceKey: 'id'
});
Exam.belongsTo( examCategory, {
    foreignKey: 'exam_id',
    targetKey: 'id'
});
sequelize.sync();
sequelize.sync({ force: true });
```

add above code in your file where your are associating the tables it will add foreign_key in your table as name exam_id you can give it name whatever you want

you can know more about foreignKey and relationship between tables in this [doc](https://sequelize.org/v3/docs/associations/)

check this [repository](https://github.com/Arya4514/Node_Shop) so you can understand how to use sequelize
and also a [boilerplate](https://github.com/talyssonoc/node-api-boilerplate) of node sequelize

Comment: Hi @Arya, I have tried your solution but got an error I have updated the question as per your answer with error.

Comment: update your app.js file as i have shown in my answer and than try

Comment: I have already updated that in the question please check :)

Comment: for reference at the bottom of question I've added my public github repository of the code.

Comment: if it helped give upvote  and accept answer so it will help others to understand